# getSkuDetails() returns 0 items returns empty array DETAILS_LIST

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am building the "inapp" billing system in my application. 
After i execute

```
skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3, "my_app_package_name", "inapp", bundle);
ArrayList<String> responseList = skuDetails.getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");
```

I always get `responseList.size()` equal to 0, even if i have set 2 items in "in-app products" in the developer console, and i am passing them to:

```
ArrayList<String> skuList = new ArrayList<String> ();
skuList.add("first_id");
skuList.add("second_id");
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", bundle);
```

The app is currently in Draft.

The operation result code is 0.

I double checked the base64 key i pass to:

```
mHelper = new IabHelper(this,Config.getBase64publicKey());
```

that i got from services and API menu.

I tried `.getSkuDetails()` both in main thread or in an asynctask.

Can somebody help me out or suggest other things to check?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Draft app testing is no long supported for testing in-app purchases. Hence you are getting an empty response.

1. You need to move them to alpha or beta channel 
   or
2. Add a static response.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#draft_apps

Comment: It worked thanks, i had to wait 10 hours or so before the change became effective. Anyway i didn't find in the docs i had to switch to alpha to do the testing...

Answer (score 5):

For me personally, I had set the SkuType incorrectly. For example, I had used `params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);` instead of  `params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);` when my app is a subscription based app.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same issue with BillingCient 4.0. My problem was that the development version I was testing against used a different package name than the production version.

Using the correct package name resolved the issue - you can get non-zero sku details from the billing client in a development build.

Comment: When you say the development version. Do you mean a version of your application?

Comment: @musterjunk yes

Comment: I finally solved my issues with proguard -keep class * extends com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson { *; }
-keep class com.google.api.services.drive.* { *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.google.api.client.util.Key { *; } and moving it to an alpha

Comment: OMG give this chap a beer, I feel so stupid, I had `applicationIdSuffix ".debug"` in the gradle files

Answer (score 1):

Previously you could test an app by uploading an unpublished "draft" version. This functionality is no longer supported. However, you can test your app with static responses even before you upload it to the Google Play Store. For more information, see Test with static responses.

Source [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#draft_apps)

Comment: whoever made it like this has no brain. It's a real beauty.