# Test In-App Billing with library in debug

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm implementing in-app billing and when I try to test, I get this error message: 
This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play

There is a related Stackoverflow post here:
[This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068686/this-version-of-the-application-is-not-configured-for-billing-through-google-pla)

What is your workflow for testing your in-app purchases?

Comment: I've always used the alpha channel with only one account (mine) as alpha tester

Comment: That is a good idea! There is no way to build the app in debug so you can see the logs?

Comment: The first answer in you link has a link on how to debug with a release certificate

Comment: draft in-app testing is not longer supported https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46887805/getskudetails-returns-0-items-returns-empty-array-details-list/46888790#46888790